# Changing stroke color after live trace using a sketch

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, scanning

I am a beginner trying to learn Illustrator and this is really driving me crazy.

I have a picture of a caricature of my grandmother.  I want to make it editable and change the colors so I can put it on a t-shirt.

I have already cleaned up the image in Photoshop and filled the lines onto an empty layer. I placed the PSD into Illustrator, live traced the image, expanded it, and ungrouped it.

Everything goes fine until I try to change the stroke color. No matter what I do, it will only change to shades of gray.

I think what I want to do is called "converting hand-drawn sketch to vector" but I'm not sure.

[image: grandma caricature]

Answer (score 1):

The document or shape may be in "Greyscale" mode. If you open the Color tab, and click on the options menu, is it set to "Greyscale"? You can select whichever color mode you want from this menu...

[image: Color tab options]

Note: You may need to select the shapes/strokes in question to apply the change, but that should do it.